# YouTrack checkin commands aren't recognized

Tags: mercurial, teamcity, youtrack

We are using YouTrack, TeamCity and mercurial. When we commit to our hg repository, we are using the checkin command for YouTrack in the form of `#issue-id [command]`

For example: 
`#Issue-10 Fixed`

When I then view this in YouTrack, the build is associated with the correct YouTrack issue, however "Fixed" is in red and says it is an unrecognized command. I've read through numerous SO topics on this, and they all elude to it just working after they have the right VCS user setup. In my case, I have the right user setup, it just doesn't recognize the command.

Any thoughts?

Edit:
Here is a screenshot of the states that are defined. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 possible problems:
- you do not have state Fixed
- there is State-Machine attached to field State - in this case you should use appropriate Action name

Comment: There is a state-machine attached to the field, yes. "Fixed" is one of those states.

Comment: "Fixed" is target state, but Action should be used to transit into this state. Click at States field on Issue and you will see list of all available "action (target state)" for current state, smth like "fix (Fixed)" so you should use "fix" in this case.

Comment: Thanks Botsman, you were right. The action was Fix, not fixed.